# Retracting flags on comments

Tags: support, flagging

I flagged a comment. Later, after some thought and after additional comments from the author of the original comment, I decided the flag was unnecessary.

How do I retract that flag? To retract a flag on a post, one needs merely click on 'flag' again, and the option to retract appears. Clicking on the flag next to the comment, however, produces no results.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can retract comment flags.  If you want to communicate with the moderators about it, you could flag the post and ask mods to disregard your comment flag.  I can't think of a better way.

If the moderator who looks at it doesn't think the comment should be deleted, your flag will be dismissed.  If the moderator thinks it should be deleted, then it would probably have gotten deleted eventually anyway so don't worry about it.  Comments aren't meant to live forever; they often do hang around a long time, but if they get cleaned up, people shouldn't get too upset about that.

Comment: Correct. You can only retract post flags, not comment flags. :)